# Is it possible to match a document based on whether a document contains a set of objects?

Tags: elasticsearch

Given a scenario where I have a root document with an array of objects. 
Is it possible to return a document that contains a set of objects?

For instance:

doc 1

```
{
   "name": "someName"
   "date": "someDate"
   "anArray" : [
         {"key1": "value1", "key2":"value2"},
         {"key1": "value3", "key2":"value4"}...]
}
```

doc 2

```
{
   "name": "someOtherName"
   "date": "someOtherDate"
   "anArray" : [
         {"key1": "value1", "key2":"value2"}, 
         {"key1": "value4", "key2":"value3"}...]
}
```

I want a query that will match and return **Doc1** based on : 
documents that contains object in the anArray with key1 = value1 && key 2=value2 AND also has object in the anArray with key1=value3 and key2= value4

Is this possible?

Comment: If not, are there any suggestions on how to approach these type of use cases OTHER than doing client side joins & filters.    

Is it possible to pipeline filters to resolve this?  

For instance:  First retrieve a list of documents with Object Key1 & key2 values with value 1 & value 2.  Then from the result, filter out Objects with Key1 & Key 2 = value3 & value 4

Comment: This is also not a nested object query.  I am not trying to match 1. I am trying to match multiple.  

Something like: NEST1(match Key1,Key2,Value1,Value2) && NEST2(match key1,Key2,Value3,Value4)

Comment: If you're trying to match multiple objects inside an array, then you have to use the `nested` data type for that array.

Comment: I see,  so the only possibility is to do: 
i.e. 

Nested Filter 1 -> match "key1","value1" && "key2","value2".
Follow by 
Nested Filter 2 ->match "key1","value3", &&"key2","value4"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine multiple nested filters on the outer query to achieve this - as Val suggested.